# Log out of Java application after 60 seconds of inactivity?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, timer

I have developed a Java Swing Application and I want to make it so that if there is inactivity for about 60 seconds, it automatically logs out. I have tried using java timers but out of the many examples I have tried, none of them seem to work.

Here is the latest one I have tried (and the only one that did not have any errors in the code):

```
int seconds;
    Timer timer;
    Toolkit toolkit;
    public void AutoLogout()
    {
        toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(null, 5000);
        if(seconds == 0)
        {
            LoginPage lp = new LoginPage();
            lp.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }
    }
```

However when I run the application it get the following output in the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:399)
    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:193)
    at AdminMainPage.AutoLogout(AdminMainPage.java:1078)
    at AdminMainPage.<init>(AdminMainPage.java:23)
    at AdminMainPage$35.run(AdminMainPage.java:1289)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I have tried several examples from Stackoverflow but none of them work. How else can I go about getting the system to logout automatically after 60 seconds of inactivity?

Comment: Don't use a TimerTask. You should be using a Swing Timer. Once the Timer fires you want your code to execute on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Application Inactiviy](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/) for a simple class that will invoke an Action after a given period of time.

The code uses an `AWTEventListener` to listen for events. Every time an event is generated a `Swing Timer` is restarted. When the `Swing Timer` fires the `Action` you specify is invoked.

Comment: This is one of the examples I found and I cannot get it to work. The application just continued running after a minute had passed.

Comment: Well the problem I had with it was that no matter what I tried I could not call it up to the class I wanted it too. Or am I suppose to implement it in a different way?

Comment: You were given the 5-6 lines of code. I have no idea what you are doing if you can't copy those lines of code. You have your LoginPage which presumably is the frame you want to close so that is what you use in the Action.

Comment: Okay let me ask you this. That link that you gave me. It's a normal Java class right? Once I have created that class on my side, how would I actually get it to work with my application. Because I have tried calling it the normal way and it did nothing. So maybe show me how you implemented it and I can maybe see where I'm going wrong

Comment: I showed you the code. in your main method you create a JFrame (you don't need to add any components to the frame or anything. Then you make the frame visible. Then you add the listener to the frame. Literally you just copy the code for the blog to the main() method. Although after creating the listener you may want to add `listener.setIntervalInMillis(5000);` so the frame will close in 5 seconds instead of waiting minutes.

Comment: I tried that and it just gives an error saying "Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context". But what I understand you saying here is that I must put all those lines of code in the main method which doesn't seem right. After going through that code I still don't see what it is suppose to do after the timer reaches 0. It just says action in the method. Am I suppose to put what I want it to do in that section?

Comment: @Osiris93, `it just gives an error saying..`  - So define all your variables in the main() method. This is basic Java. The problem is with your code not the class. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows the code you used. `I must put all those lines of code in the main method` - No that is not true. If is the easiest way to test the class and prove it works!  In real life all you need is a reference to the frame you want to close. So wherever you make the frame visible you would then add the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29), you will see:

```
throws a NullPointerException - if task is null
```

Which is exactly what you do in your line

```
timer.schedule(null, 5000);
```

That explains the Exception that's being thrown at you. I don't think a scheduler is the right way to go here since each user activity should reset the timer.

Comment: But anything else I put there besides null gives me an error

Comment: And what exactly did you try? The parameter needs to be an instance of ``TimerTask``.

Comment: Various things, and all of them gave errors.The one example used a class, but when I tried that it still gave an error. I'm still trying to understand java timers. What would be a suitable parameter to use.

Comment: Don't use a TimerTask. You should be using a Swing Timer. Once the Timer fires you want your code to execute on the Event Dispatch Thread

Comment: Are you saying use javax.swing.Timer; ?